# Why is Angular routerLink (without leading slash) broken when navigating back to empty path?

Tags: angular, routerlink

Let's take this basic navigation tree:

- primary

  - secondary

    - deep

Look at my [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukxb4a).

My routes are

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: PageParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: PageChildPrimaryComponent
      },
      {
        path: "secondary",
        component: PageChildSecondaryComponent
      },
      {
        path: "secondary/deep",
        component: PageDeepComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Using `<a routerLink="..">`, I can successfully navigate up one level,
and using `<a routerLink="../..">` two levels.
However, when I use double dots to go back to the "primary" page from any deeper page,
any `routerLink` that doesn't start with a slash is messed up;
the root part of the URL (`https://angular-ukxb4a.stackblitz.io/` or `localhost:4200/`, when run locally) is replaced with `%28`. When I use `<a routerLink="/">` (slash instead of double dots), everything is fine.

***Why*** is that happening?

Comment: You need to use hash url strategy like this in `app-routing.component.ts` file  `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})]`,

Comment: @GaurangDhorda With hash, using the "no slash" and "double dot" links to go to the secondary page and back to the primary page multiple times, the url is building up like `https://angular-ukxb4a.stackblitz.io/#//(/(/(/(/()))))`

Answer (score 0):

The URL you want to go is

> https://angular-ukxb4a.stackblitz.io/secondary

**NOT**

> https://%28secondary%29/

The starting slash will append path to your existing path.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, but why does the link become `https://%28secondary%29/`?